# How to expand region of a plot saved through hgexport?

Tags: matlab

So I used the command

hgexport(gcf, 'figure1.jpg', hgexport('factorystyle'), 'Format', 'jpeg');

on my graph, and I get this weird graph below. Is there a way to auto-save images I generate with Matlab - with all the axes expanded out to full screen, so that all these plots won't be squished together?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Once a figure is exported out of matlab with `hgexport` or any other printing function, the image properties are definitive. This means that zooming/expanding will be very limited.

To anticipate some extra work on an image, one can save a figure as a `.fig` file (using [`hgsave`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hgsave.html?searchHighlight=hgsave) or [`saveas`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html)). Once opened, such `.fig` files behave just like regular figures: one can zoom, expand, span, full screen, change colors, change data, *etc*. To export a figure, you can set all these properties and then proceed to a `saveas`.

In addition, if you want to export your figure using `hgexport`, you can do

```
style = hgexport('factorystyle');
style.Bounds = 'tight';
hgexport(gcf,'-clipboard',style,'applystyle', true);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! I could try the .fig option, but that isn't necessarily going to work for some applications. I also tried your hgexport solution, but it didn't really do anything differently.